# Does pH affect the activation energy of decomposition of hydrogen peroxide using iron (III) nitrate solution?

Tags: kinetics, ph, catalysis

I know that pH can affect the activation energy of the decomposition of hydrogen peroxide when catalase is used, as catalase is an enzyme. However, if I use some nonenzymatic catalysts like iron (III) ions or manganese (II) oxide, is controlling pH important anymore if I want to measure the activation energy of the reaction? Any response will be appreciated.

Comment: As the reaction rates would strongly depend on pH, controlling pH is essential if the Ea is determined e.g. from the Arrhenius equation and temperature dependence of the reation rate. As the rate=f(T, pH).   As pH affects availability of respective forms of iron and manganese in solution or behaviour of surface functional groups.

Comment: @Poutnik would you mind explaining more about "pH affects availability of respective forms of iron and manganese in solution or behaviour of surface functional groups"? I haven't been introduced to this concept yet (still a secondary school student). Thank you!